# Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.0.5 but source was compiled with: 8.1.0 Tensorflow2 Object Detection

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm using Colab, and I'm getting the error when I'm training with Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API. Tensorflow version is 2.6.2 and library is downloaded from official repo. This issue just appeared overnight, same code was working until the day before, which makes me think some internal changes happened, but I don't know how to fix this. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions I found:

1. Downgrade TF to match the CUDA and CUDAnn
2. Upgrade the CUDAnn

Please check [this related GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/554).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, the solution was to upgrade CUDAnn

Comment: how did you upgrade CUDNN on colab ? I am still struggling